# Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as a condition

Tags: flutter

How can solve this problem of null safety

```dart
class _SelectEmpTaskState extends State<SelectEmpTask> {
  bool? _value = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            print("object");
            _value = !_value // Not working
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what's not working, we need error messages and details to help out. We can't solve the problem without knowing what the problem is

Comment: (_value =!_value  )not working and the error message is (A nullable expression can't be used as a condition.
Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as a condition) @Jacob

Answer (score 0):

You are using flutter version with sound null safety or you have enabled null safety

The first problem is no semicolon in the code below

```
_value = !_value // Not working
```

Second change use:

```
late bool _value = false
```

instead of `bool? _value = false;`

complete source code below:

```
class _SelectEmpTaskState extends State {
  late bool _value = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            print("object");
            _value = !_value; // Not working
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I use late bool butt still not working at onChanged: (bool? value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _value = value;
                                  });
                                }), // this function of checkbox @I_am_programmer